# select records where condition is true in one record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select cid, project, and owner from rows in the table below where one or more rows for a cid/project combination has an owner of 1.

```
cid | project | phase | task | owner
-----------------------------------
1   | 1       | 1     | 1    | 1
1   | 1       | 1     | 2    | 2
1   | 1       | 1     | 3    | 2
2   | 1       | 1     | 1    | 1
2   | 1       | 1     | 2    | 1
3   | 1       | 1     | 3    | 2
```

My output table should look like the this:

```
cid | project | phase | task | owner
-----------------------------------
1   | 1       | 1     | 1    | 1
1   | 1       | 1     | 2    | 2
1   | 1       | 1     | 3    | 2
2   | 1       | 1     | 1    | 1
2   | 1       | 1     | 2    | 1
```

The below query is what I came up with. It does seem to test okay, but my confidence is low. Is the query an effective way to solve the problem?

```
select task1.cid, task1.project, task1.owner
from 
(select cid, project, owner from table) task1
right join 
(select distinct cid, project, owner from table where owner = 1) task2
on task1.cid = task2.cid and task1.project = task2.project
```

(I did not remove the phase and task columns from the sample output so that it would be easier to compare.)

Comment: Your query is fine, although I would use a regular `join` rather than an outer join.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Gordon. I just refreshed myself on joins. I see now that an inner join (join) would be more to the point.  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Isn't the middle select superfluous?  Couldn't you just `JOIN` the first with the last directly?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Like scaisEdge's join below. I was thinking "well maybe it will optimize things up a little if I don't try and work with all of the columns..." But maybe I am just making it harder then it needs to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a IN clause

```
  select cid, project, owner
  from table
  where cid in (select distinct id from table where owner = 1)
```

or a inner join  with a subquery

```
  select a.cid, a.project, a.owner
  from table a 
  INNER JOIN ( select distinct cid , project
        from table where owner = 1
  ) t on t.cid = a.cid and t.project = a.project
```

Comment: `in` can have a pretty significant performance hit if there's a large number of records in the real data.  Not to say it shouldn't be used, but it should be used with caution.

Comment: you could have some performance problem with a IN clause with relavant item ..but for the inner join version  .. you can use proper index  for mantain high  performance... if for this reason that the two version are exposed ..

Comment: thanks for the input everyone. scaisEdge your inner join works fine when I replace id with cid and project.

Comment: @scaisEdge - cool, didn't know that.  Guess you learn something new every day.

Comment: @user2366842  thanks  but   if your think my answer  is useful  .. SO let you rate the answer  for this